# Why does black support for Trump increase when the density or concentration of blacks in the neighborhood decreases?

Tags: united-states

I read this article in The Guardian that said that black GOP support goes up as the density of the black population goes down. I mean by "density" the proportion of black population in an area. I have looked at data on the internet and it suggests that this is the case. For example, Trump got about 8% of the black vote nationally but only 3% of the vote in Detroit.

Why is this?

Article: https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2020/feb/14/black-americans-are-not-a-monolithic-group-so-stop-treating-us-like-one

Comment: It's not really anything specifically about black people, Detroit is more dense than the US average and denser areas are less GOP, regardless of race.

Comment: aside: using an adjective (black) as a noun is incorrect (adjectives aren't plural) and often considered offensive; ask the shorts, the balds, and the olds.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not finding a systematic analysis of the data to address this question, but I suspect it results from the intersection of two sets of facts:

1. "Today, **75 percent of African-Americans  live  in  cities  or  suburbs**.  15  percent  live  in  smaller  cities  and  towns,  while  just  10  percent  live  in  rural  areas,  mainly  in  the  South. [(source)](https://www.niskanencenter.org/wp-content/uploads/old_uploads/2019/06/Wilkinson-Density-Divide-Final.pdf)
2. **Trump won only 35 percent of the vote in urban areas** but 62% in rural areas. ([source](https://www.statista.com/statistics/632430/voter-turnout-of-the-exit-polls-of-the-2016-elections-by-rural-urban-area/))

Urban and rural voters have all kinds of strong differences in terms of general political attitudes and values. [(source)](https://www.pewsocialtrends.org/2018/05/22/urban-suburban-and-rural-residents-views-on-key-social-and-political-issues/) So my hypothesis would be that those districts with a high density of black voters are more likely to be urban, and that the black vote follows the general voting trend of urban/Democrat vs. rural/Republican. Perhaps someone more ambitious and adept with data can test this directly.